# How does SQL SELECT statement work?

Tags: sql

I created a table with id as primary key, firstname, lastname, email as fields. I issued the following query:

```
 "SELECT email,COUNT(email) FROM mytable;"
```

The result had the first value for email i.e from the first record and the total number of values from the column 'email'. Why did it not display all the different values for email from different records?

Comment: The Count() method returns a single value

Comment: Could you show the sample data and expected output?

Comment: i entered 3 different values for email. 'abc@gmai.com', def@gmail.com', 'ghi@gmail.com'. I wanted the result to display all these value along '3' from count function i used in the query. Instead it displayed abc@gmail.com,3 in the result.

Comment: "Count" is  aggregate function. You should use  SELECT email,COUNT(email) FROM mytable Group by email

Comment: You need to look into `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html says:

> Without GROUP BY, there is a single group and it is nondeterministic which name value to choose for the group.

Like with any grouping query, the `COUNT(*)` returns the count of rows in the group, and reduces the result to one row per group.

But since you don't have any GROUP BY clause, the whole table is treated as one big group, and the result only returns one row.

The `email` column returns one of the email values in the group. Technically this value is chosen arbitrarily from one of the rows in the group.

In practice, MySQL's implementation chooses the value from the first row read from the group, the order of which depends on which index was used to scan the table. Though this behavior of picking the first row is not documented and they make no guarantee to make this behavior the same from version to version.

It's better to avoid depending on queries that return an arbitrary, implementation-dependent value. It makes your code harder to maintain, because there's a risk it will change if you upgrade MySQL and they change their undocumented behavior.

To protect you from making these sorts of arbitrary queries, newer versions of MySQL enforce an SQL mode called ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. That option makes it an error to run a query like that one you show. For what it's worth, the query is already an error in most other brands of SQL database.